# MySQL suddenly has stopped working on the server

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

When I run sudo service MySQL start I get:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I run `journalctl -xe | tail -50` I get:

```
    -- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 30 10:55:58 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 30 10:55:58 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 30 10:55:58 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 30 10:55:58 servername systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 30 10:55:58 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Apr 30 10:56:00 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 30 10:56:28 servername systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 30 10:56:28 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 30 10:56:28 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 30 10:56:29 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 30 10:56:29 servername systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 30 10:56:29 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Apr 30 10:56:30 servername sshd[12035]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=150.95.153.82  user=backup
Apr 30 10:56:31 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 30 10:56:33 servername sshd[12035]: Failed password for backup from 150.95.153.82 port 48284 ssh2
Apr 30 10:56:33 servername sshd[12035]: Received disconnect from 150.95.153.82 port 48284:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Apr 30 10:56:33 servername sshd[12035]: Disconnected from 150.95.153.82 port 48284 [preauth]
```

I'm not sure if `ufw` is causing the issue, when I run `sudo ufw status numbered` I get:

```
Status: active

 To                         Action      From
 --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 22                         ALLOW IN    185.75.---            
[ 4] 22                         ALLOW IN    82.69.---              
[ 5] 22                         ALLOW IN    81.----              
[ 6] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 7] 22                         ALLOW IN    185.----          
[ 8] 873                        ALLOW IN    185.----/24          
[ 9] 3306                       ALLOW IN    109.----/24          
[10] 22                         ALLOW IN    109.----/24          
[11] 3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[12] 3306                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[13] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    185.2----           
[14] 3306                       ALLOW IN    185.2----           
[15] 3306/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
```

Comment: Do you recognize the IP address? Is it yours?

Comment: The ip address starting with 150? No that's not mine, mine starts with 185.